# How to repeat string using the array of input

Tags: arrays, linux, string, bash, shell

So a user can input this in the bash script when ask: `1,2,3,4,5,6` comma separated.

Now what I wanted is to append and repeat it with the string so the results would be like:

`hi1 hi2 hi3 hi4 hi5 hi6`

This works with:

`"hi"{1,2,3,4,5,6}`

The problem is using the user input to the loop to be used as the parameter to it. I tried using this but it does not work.

`"hi"{$USERINPUT}`

I do not have deep experience with bash to know this part.

Comment: Please show your script.

Answer (score 3):

Using bash pattern substitution and `printf`:

```
printf "hi%s " ${USERINPUT//,/ }
```

`printf` does not require a loop and prints as many strings as there are arguments.

The bash substitution is `${parameter/pattern/string}` which is documented in the bash man page.

Comment: I am using `read a;printf "hi%s" ${a//,/}` but for some reasons I can't get it to work if i give input a as 1,2,3,4 , can you please suggest what am I doing wrong

Comment: @Inder you forgot a space before the closing bracket `}`. Your command should be `read a;printf "hi%s" ${a//,/ }`

Comment: thank you that works as expected

Comment: @oliv Can you tell my whyu I need to put a space at the end?

Comment: Because the substitution changes a comma with a space

Answer (score 0):

How about using `sed`?

```
$ echo "$USERINPUT" | sed 's/[0-9][0-9]*/hi&/g;s/,/ /g'
hi1 hi2 hi3 hi4 hi5 hi6
```